# vuex "url" of undefined using axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

I've recently learnt a bit about vuex and store.
I was about to use it for calling my api but it keeps saying my
url is undefined.
here is my vuex codes:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";
const url = 'https://myurl'
export default createStore({
  state: {
    catList: [],
    transactList: [],
    user: [],
    requestList: [],
    catInList: [],
    productList: [],
    errorMs: '',
    calling: false,
    mobile: ''
  },
  getters: {
    allUsers: (state) => state.user,
    transactList: (state) => state.transactList,
    categoryList: (state) => state.catList,
    requestList: (state) => state.requestList,
    productList: (state) => state.productList,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_Users (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },

  actions: {
    checkAuth() {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : ''
      axios.defaults.baseURL = url
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
      axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    async axiosPost ({dispatch} ,{url}) {
      dispatch('checkAuth')
      await axios.post(url+'/login', {
        mobile: this.mobile
      }).then(response => {
        this.calling = false
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
      })
    },
    async axiosGet ({dispatch} , {url, formData}) {
      dispatch('checkAuth')
      await axios.get(url, formData).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }

  },
  created() {
  }
})
```

actually I wanted to define my api globally, so that I can use it for different components only by adding `url + '/login'` but I'm not sure why it keeps saying my url is not defined.
can anyone help me with the errors?

[image]

Comment: Look at this setup: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios

Comment: The variable is undefined because you didn't define it. It's not specific to Axios or Vuex. It's incorrect to set `axios.defaults` on call, it's supposed to be set once.